# WPF Expander Hierarchical data Template of 2 levels

Tags: wpf, xaml, expander, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a repeating data structure like this

```
public class Chapter
{   
    public string id { get; set; }      
    public string name { get; set; }            
    public List<BPage> pages { get; set; }                      
    public List<SubChapter> chapters { get; set; }
}
public class SubChapter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<BPage> pages { get; set; }
    public string ParentPageId { get; set; }
    public List<SubChapter> chapters { get; set; }
}
public class BPage
{
    public string name { get; set; }     
    public string label { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the xaml i am using , But this xaml is giving only one level of data back to me . Second level is missing completely

ie if Chapter 1 contains 2 subchapters and pages , then those info is missing
    Chapter 1
       page 1
       page 2
       Chapter 1.1
           page 1a 
           page 1b
       Chapter 1.2 
            page 2a
            page 2b

And xaml is

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="TOCView"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding chapters}">
            <Expander>
                <Expander.Header>
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ChapterHeadStyle}"  Content="{Binding name}"></Label>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ItemsControl Margin="25,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding pages}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding}"  Click="btnNavigateToPage_Click"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=BookPageStyle}"  Content="{Binding Path=label}" >
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Expander>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: `HierarchicalDataTemplate` can also define it's `ItemTemplate`, see if that is what you are looking for. I would suggest you to combine `Chapter` & `SubChapter` class as the only difference is `ParentPageId` which can be left null in case of root chapters. then defining the nested templates would be much easier.

Comment: Already there is one ItemTemplate defined here for HierarchicalDataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused because you have only provided one `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, but you want to define two hierarchical levels. Therefore, you need to provide another `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for your second level. Please note that you do *not* have to define them in the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property, instead defining them both in a `Resources` section:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:Chapter}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPropertyInSubChapterClass}">
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:SubChapter}">
    ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionPropertyInBPageClass}">
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

As long as you *don't* specify the `x:Key` directive for either of them, they will be implicitly applied, so you won't have to provide any value for the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` property.

Comment: I am confused how to combine these 2 with expander . Since i want to show only one chapter & child's at a time . So how can i make it as a complete code

Comment: As I said, *define them both in a `Resources` section* [and] *they will be implicitly applied*. Remember, a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` is just an extended `DataTemplate`... treat it in the same way.